# How can I add list parameters to a LINQ query?

Tags: c#, linq, list, linq-to-entities

I have two parameters passed to the method and I need to attach them to the final query list.

(1st parameter)

```
string[] Price= new string[5];
Price= new string[] { "50", "25", "35" };
```

(2nd parameter)

```
List<string> DiscountPrice= new List<string>();
DiscountPrice.Add ("10"); 
DiscountPrice.Add ("5");
DiscountPrice.Add ("3");


var list= (from d in context.List
           where ....
           select new MyNewList
           {
                 Name = d.Name,                    
                 Country = d.Country,
                 **Price = ??** //how do I attach the parameters one by one? In the order they were saved?
                 **DiscountPrice** = ?? 

           }).ToList<MyNewList>();
```

Comment: Do you want to use these parameters as query parameters or just have them included in the result? (by your question I assume the last)

Comment: Are you using a Join to these collections ? Are you looking to add a single price and DiscountedPrice or you want to assign the collection ?

Comment: I just want to include them in the result, add each price & discounted price to the collection. I hope it makes sense, thx

Comment: What are the types of `Price` and `DiscountPrice` in the `MyNewList` class?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like you want to match list elements by index.  You can iterate from zero to the number of list elements and access each element by its index:

```
var prices = new string[] { "50", "25", "35" };
var discountPrices = new List<string>() { "10", "5", "3" };

var items = (from d in context.List
             where ....
             select new { d.Name, d.Country }).ToList();

var list =  (from index in Enumerable.Range(0, items.Count())
             select new MyNewList
                    {
                        Name = items[index].Name,                    
                        Country = items[index].Country,
                        Price = prices[index],
                        DiscountPrice = discountPrices[index]
                    }).ToList();
```

Another way is to [Zip](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267698.aspx) everything together:

```
var list = items.Zip(prices, (item, price) => new { item, price })
                .Zip(discountPrices, (x, discountPrice) => new { x.item, x.price, discountPrice})
                .Select(x => new MyNewList
                             {
                                 Name = x.item.Name,                    
                                 Country = x.item.Country,
                                 Price = x.price,
                                 DiscountPrice = x.discountPrice
                             })
                .ToList();
```